# Deployment of a UWP on Windows 10 but not on the store

Tags: deployment, uwp

I have been working for the last few months on an UWP that I now need to share with my co-workers. I have been working with Visual Studio on my own but it's time that my colleagues use it as well. I have been digging through the documentation and on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find a way to deploy my app. I would need to have  a .exe like any other program that I would click and then the code would start running as if I was running it through Visual Studio.

I am new to UWPs so feel free to ask for further information if you need it. I am working with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there. You mean your co-workers just experience and use it, not write code, right?

Here is what u can do, Click "Project", "Store", "Create Application Package"

**My vs is Chinese version**, I don't know the translation is right or not. You can see the picture below.

[image]

And you will see, select "I want to create side-load package". Click next.

[image]

Then Click "Create" in the bottom. Wait a few minutes. When it done, vs will popup a dialog.

[image]

Annnnnnnnnd, last, go to packages folder, copy your_project_Test folder to your co-workers. On there pc, right click "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1", and select "Use PowerShell to Run". Just a few seconds, it will appear in your start menu.

Comment: Your translation is 99% accurate, your solution worked perfectly, thank you.